# How to integrate PortAudio in iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, swift, audio, portaudio

I want to integrate PortAudio Library in iOS. For that,I followed port audio documentation Link: http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_mac_coreaudio.html

**I got error**:

```
     ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.a, building for iOS-arm64 but 
     attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
     Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
     "_Pa_Initialize", referenced from:
     -[AudioPlayerPortAudio initilizeData] in AudioPlayerPortAudio.o
     "_Pa_GetErrorText", referenced from:
     -[AudioPlayerPortAudio initilizeData] in AudioPlayerPortAudio.o
     ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think, it's integrating into MacOS not iOS.I didn't found anything, Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Follow this guide to compile the library for arm64: http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_mac_coreaudio.html

Comment: Thanks Scriptable, I run i ./configure && make in terminal.
I got, configure: error: Could not find 10.5 to 10.12 SDK.

Comment: not sure on that one sorry, i'm not familiar with MacOS development. I just recognised it complaining about the architecture in the error

Comment: no problem Scriptable.

Comment: Did you get any success in creating portaudio library for ios?

Comment: No, I didn't get